# Is the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\zeta(1/2,k)-\zeta(1/2,k+x)$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, closed-form, zeta-functions

Consider the series 
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\zeta(1/2,k)-\zeta(1/2,k+x)$$
where $\zeta(s,k)$ is the Hurwitz zeta function.

Is the series convergent point wise or uniformly on $(-1, +\infty)$?

Does the series have a special closed form?

Comment: Same trick as Jack : $$\Gamma(s)\zeta(s,a) = \Gamma(s)\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+a)^{-s} =\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-(n+a)x}dx=\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} \frac{e^{-ax}}{1-e^{-x}}dx$$ so $$F(s,a) =\Gamma(s)\sum_{k=1}^\infty \zeta(s,k)-\zeta(s,k+a) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} \frac{e^{-kx}(1-e^{-ax})}{1-e^{-x}}dx \\ = \int_0^\infty x^{s-1} \frac{1-e^{-ax}}{(1-e^{-x})(e^x-1)}dx$$

$\frac{1-e^{-ax}}{(1-e^{-x})(e^x-1)}$ has a simple pole at $x=0$ and decreases exponentially as $x \to \infty$, whence $F(s,a)$ converges for $Re(s) > 1$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have:
$$ \zeta\left(\frac{1}{2},k\right)=\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\sum_{n\geq 0}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+k}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\right]\tag{1} $$
that through the inverse Laplace transform turns into the following integral representation:
$$ \zeta\left(\frac{1}{2},k\right)=\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{(1-k)s}-1}{\sqrt{\pi s}(e^s-1)}\,ds \tag{2}$$
In particular:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{k\geq 1}\left[\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2},k\right)-\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2},k+x\right)\right]&=&\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{e^{(1-k)s}-e^{(1-k-x)s}}{\sqrt{\pi s}(e^s-1)}\,ds\\&=&\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-e^{-sx}}{4\sqrt{\pi s}\sinh^2\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)}\,ds\end{eqnarray*}\tag{3}$$
**is divergent** due to the behaviour of the integrand function in a right neighbourhood of the origin, $\frac{x}{\sqrt{\pi s^3}}$, leading to a non-integrable singularity. That also follows from
$$\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2},k\right)-\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2},k+x\right)\sim\frac{x}{\sqrt{k}}\tag{4}$$
for large values of $k$. $\left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right\}_{k\geq 1}$ is not a summable sequence.

Comment: I did not have any bad intentions, Excuse me please.