# ‎Limit of $‎\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{x}{\sqrt {n+N}}+\sum_{k=1}^N\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+k+x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt {n+k}}‎ $‎?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, special-functions, closed-form

Consider the functional sequence 
$$‎\delta‎_N(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{x}{\sqrt {n+N}}\right)+\sum_{k=1}^N\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+k+x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt {n+k}}‎
\right)$$‎
‎By ‎some ‎theorems ‎through ‎my ‎research, I found that $‎\delta‎_N(x)‎$ ‎is ‎convergent on $(-2,+\infty)$‎ as ‎‎$‎‎N\to\infty$ ‎, but I need the limit function of this exactly. Anyone can help me to find it or present a closed form of it?

Comment: Would you explain more, how do you obtain this answer? Thanks.

Comment: Somewhat unrelated to the question itself, but it seems that you are not accepting answers in more than half of your previously asked questions. Who would be eager to answer a question knowing that they wouldn't get any feedback?

Comment: I am accepting all of my answers, and I thank everyone that solved them or led me to clear them. But I changed something to get the best and nearest answers for my problems.

Comment: You have just removed the $\checkmark$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2186435/is-the-series-sum-k-1-infty-zeta1-2-k-zeta1-2-kx-convergent), for instance. Do you mind explaining why?

Comment: I have removed the ✓ because I thought that perhaps anyone can find or present other different answers. Also I thought that sharing the knowledge is  one of aims of members. Moreover I am sure that it is convergent on $(-2,+\infty)$. Thanks.

Comment: Excuse me, I miss $x$ in part one, Now I edited it.

Comment: Silently removing the acceptance or not leaving any comment to existing answers does not sound like an appropriate way of communicating with other users in this community. Also, now \begin{align*}\lim_{N\to\infty}\delta_N(x) &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi u}} \frac{1}{e^u - 1} \left( x - \frac{1-e^{-xu}}{e^u - 1} \right) \, dx \\ &= (1+x)\left( \zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) - \zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}, x+2\right) \right) - \left( \zeta\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right) - \zeta\left(-\frac{1}{2}, x+2\right) \right). \end{align*}

Comment: You can remove the ${\large \checkmark}$ $\color{red}{\textsf{AFTER}}$ you find that a new arriving answer is somehow better than the previously accepted one but not $\color{red}{\textsf{BEFORE}}$ the arriving of the new one. You don't know in advance whether a fresh new answer will be better than all the previous ones. By the way, It's currently quite difficult to beat Jack answers.

Comment: Maybe, [$\underline{\texttt{this identity}}$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.2.E8) will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks every body  specially Jack D'Aurizio. I gave him back the ✓. Please forgive me Jack, I did not have any bad intentions.

Comment: I'd like to remind all involved that it is not required of anyone to accept answers, no is there any time frame for doing so. It is absolutely up to the user who asked the question. Including taking off the checkmark if they want to get a better answer. Relevant meta questions https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20992/269624 https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2553/269624 https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13286/269624 https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10626/269624

Comment: According to Sangchul Lee, is the follwing true when $r‎<0$?

Comment: $\lim_{N\rightarrow\‎‎infty}\delta_N(x)=(1+x)\big(‎\zeta‎(-r)-‎\zeta‎(-r,x+2)‎\big)‎-\big(‎\zeta‎(r)-‎\zeta‎(r,x+2)‎\big)$